# Search for tags

Tags: taxonomy, tags, search

Is it possible, to search just for tags?

Not any other taxonomies or post types, just tag titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes its very possible, you just need to create your own search form and processing function
form:

```
<form name="tag-search" method="POST" action="">
  <input type="text" vlaue="" name="tag-q" id="tag-q">
  <input type="submit" name="tag-submit" id="tag-submit" value="Search Tags">
</form>
```

processing:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tag-submit']) && $_POST['tag-submit'] == "Search Tags" && isset($_POST['tag-q']) && $_POST['tag-q'] != ""){

    // @todo Sanity check and cleanup $_POST['tag-q'] here.

    $args = array('name__like' => $_POST['tag-q']);
    $tags = get_tags($args);
    $html = '<div class="post_tags_search_r">';
    foreach ($tags as $tag){
        $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);

        $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
        $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    echo $html;
}
?>
```

No this is something i have used in the past, the only downside to this is that `name__like` is  case-insensitive so you might want to add the [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) version to the name__like.

Comment: good hook. But this example in unsafe, we should clean up the [tag-q] to avoid problems

Comment: @Happy i agree 100%